# Query that returns the column type integer for a given table

Tags: java, oracle

JDBC supports the following:

```
ResultSet columns = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, tableName, null);
```

This way I can retrieve information for all columns in the given table including the DATA_TYPE information. That information is of type int in java.

I used the following query to retrieve column name and data type but this returns the string representation of data type and I need int :

```
select column_name, data_type from all_tab_cols where table_name = 'tablename' and owner = 'owner';
```

How does the line of java code translate to a query in Oracle DB ?
 How can I retrieve the int representation of a column ?
I would use a join but I don't know where to get the information from. Where does Oracle store these informations ?

Comment: The standard numeric datatype in Oracle is NUMBER. No differentiation between int and float/double. (If you are lucky, if a column was really meant to be integer, you will see something like NUMBER(8,0), but that is rather rare.) How do you propose to identify which columns are int and which are float/double?

Answer (score 0):

For running SQL against a DB without using any ORM tools like hibernate, you can take a look at `PreparedStatement` class.

If you want to look at the "metadata" about the columns your PreparedStatement returned, you can take a look at the `getMetaData()` method, documentation can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getMetaData()) and then ask the ResultSetMetaData about the column type: `getColumnType(<0 based index of the column you want to find the type>)` [documentation can be found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType(int))

Regarding your question about how Java translates to Query in Oracle, it is too broad to be described in an answer. I would recommend looking for a tutorial on JDBC or the official [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/).